# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::oldest does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am currently working on the creation of an API using Lumen. I have, for the example, 2 tables `users` and `users_token` with the corresponding models `User` and `UsersToken`.

The table `users_token` has 2 importants fields: `user_id` (foreign key linked with `id` field from `users` table) and `token` (a simple string).

In my model `User`, I have the method `tokens` that return all the tokens from the user using the `hasMany()` function:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function tokens()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UsersToken');
    }
}
```

The table `users_token` also contains the defaults fields `created_at` and `updated_at`. So to get the oldest modified token of an user, I decide to use the `oldest()` function of Laravel:

```php
$latestUserToken = $user->tokens->oldest('updated_at');
```

But sadly I get this error message:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::oldest does not exist.

Have someone an idea where my error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$user->tokens` return the Eloquent Collection.

`oldest` is a method of Eloquent-Builder and Query-Builder.

You need to call `oldest` method like this one:

```php
$latestUserToken = $user->tokens()->oldest('updated_at')->first();
```

Laravel order by `updated_at` asc.